# Syncing between Windows 7 and Android Jellybean with Winamp

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-s-3, media-player, winamp

I want to sync my Samsung Galaxy S3 4G to my Windows 7 PC with Winamp so I can easily sync playlists to and from my phone and computer. So I followed the instructions in Winamp's official blog: http://blog.winamp.com/2010/11/30/wirelessly-sync-music-to-your-android-phone/

It didn't work. When I click on the Discover button, nothing happens. When I right-click Devices and click Start Discovery... you guessed it - *nothing* happens! I am connected to a windows domain and connected via an Ethernet cable. Could that be preventing me from accessing the same WiFi network I have my Galaxy on?

I've done some research on this issue and it is a common problem. If anyone has found a solution to it, I'll be very glad to hear it! I love using Winamp and don't want to use any other media player.

Comment: Are you sure you checked that *enable wireless sync* option?

Comment: @Sid Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread and you may have already found an answer, but I had the same problem after installing Winamp 5 pro on an Android device. I had previously had no problems with Winamp standard on both Android & PC

I upgraded the PC version to Winamp Pro and now it all works as expected again. So I suspect you need the same version of Winamp on both platforms ie. either standard or Pro

Answer (score 0):

After some look-ups, I have to come into conclusion that you *cannot do this*. As you thought it's your Ethernet connectivity that prohibits you from this. When you are using the ethernet-connected modem device for WiFi, there is only *one* device in your WiFi network. But Winamp says, *`Make sure your PC and Android phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.`*

<sub>Note: If you really need this syncing feature, you can get a WiFi adaptor and connect your PC *and* phone to the same network and do syncing</sub>

Comment: Could you tell why this isn't possible? I haven't found a reason why this shouldn't work, and some people on the official page (linked in the question) have been unsuccessful even after trying with a WiFi dongle. There should be no difference whether the PC uses a wired or wireless connection.

Comment: @Sid I almost came to that conclusion but I don't give up very easily! And I don't know for sure that it is the Ethernet connection but I wouldn't be surprised if that was preventing me from accessing the WiFi network. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @MissZ you're welcome. do let us know if you succeed with another solution and post it here. (and yeah! DO NOT give up!!)

Comment: @Sid I will! Never give up, never surrender! ;)

Comment: @MissZ Excellent Motto

Comment: Sad to report that I never ended up finding a solid solution for this issue, apart from just waiting a while and then letting the device magically appear in the sync section of winamp. I'm now using a note 3 anyway and will see if that appears in winamp. Thanks to everyone for their answers and help! :)